# how to get the value of the selected link of mat-nav-list

Tags: angular-material, angular7

I would like to have a dynamic header.
this is my nav:

```
<mat-nav-list  [(ngModel)]="selectedOptions">
  <a mat-list-item href="" routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active-link" [value]="home" >Home</a>
  <a mat-list-item href="" routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="active-link" >About</a>
  <a mat-list-item href="" routerLink="/catalog" routerLinkActive="active-link" >Catalog</a>
</mat-nav-list>
```

when i click on home, I want to get home , if i click on About i want to get About. After i i retrieve this value withe the service and i display header component

```
<section class="title">
  <div class="title_container">
    <h1 class="font-weight-bold">{{titleTab}}</h1> // {{titleTab}} = home | About | etc...
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You could use the `ActivatedRoute` interfaceto get the information of the route you are currently on; from there you can access its parameters as well... https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute

Comment: Ok i use ActivatedRoute and it works! Thank